# Finding references to an object

Tags: c#, debugging

Is there any way to find all references to an object while debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to dig into WinDbg it is fairly easy to find references to a specific object. However, WinDbg is not the easiest tool to use.

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) has lots of info on using WinDbg.

Comment: You're welcome - I use WinDbg on a regular basis for managed code. Check out sosex.dll as well (more commands for managed debugging with WinDbg).

Comment: Thanks for the lead Brian! The complete solution using sosex would be: 1. Download sosex.dll 2. run `.load x:\path\to\sosex.dll` in WinDbg 3. use `!refs 0xaabbccdd`

Answer (score 6):

Not without using the profiling/debugger API, as far as I'm aware. (Even with the API, I don't know how to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

Not with the default tools that Visual Studio offers you. There are 3rd party "Memory Profilers" out there that will allow you to do this. I have used one myself to hunt down a "memory leak" in a .NET program.